# ArgumentOutOfRangeException at MySql execution. (MySqlConnector .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, range, connector

I am getting this exception from a MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery():

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>
> Parameter name: length

The command text is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO accounts
    (username, password, salt, pin, banned,
    staff, logged_in, points_a, points_b, points_c, birthday)
VALUES
    ('adminb', 'aea785fbcac7f870769d30226ad55b1aab850fb0979ee00481a87bc846744a646a649d30bca5474b59e4292095c74fa47ae6b9b3a856beef332ff873474cc0d3',
    'cb162ef55ff7c58c7cb9f2a580928679', '', '0, '0', '0', '0',
    '0', '0', '2010-04-18')
```

Sorry for the long string, it is a SHA512 hash.
I tried manually adding this data in the table from MySQL GUI tools, and it worked perfectly.
I see no "out of range" problem in these strings. Does anybody see something wrong?

Comment: I can't help with the index out of range, other then the obvious missing '. But you should definitely be using a parameterised query. Put the values into parameters on the command object instead of straight into a string. It will help avoid all sorts of issues, like SQL Injection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain the error message, but I can see one thing that is wrong:

```
'0,
```

There is a single quote missing. It should be this:

```
'0',
```